# The requested document was not found on this server

Tags: php, url-routing

I think I have to write it on web.config file. My server is not responding on .htaccess file. How could i convert this .htaccess to web.config file. Please help.

I am using xampp as local server where my site works completely.
But when i upload it to plesk only index page is working but all other link inside index is not working. My site is d-subidha.com Other link will show error as below.

Not Found
The requested document was not found on this server.

```
<?php
/**
 * Front controller
 *`enter code here`
 * PHP version 7.0
 */
 /**
 * Composer
 */
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
/**
 * Error and Exception handling
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_error_handler('Core\Error::errorHandler');
set_exception_handler('Core\Error::exceptionHandler');
/**
 * Sessions
 */
session_start();


/**
 * Routing
 */
$router = new Core\Router();

// Add the routes
$router->add('', ['controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'index']);

$router->add('search', ['controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'search']);

$router->add('login', ['controller' => 'Login', 'action' => 'new']);
$router->add('logout', ['controller' => 'Login', 'action' => 'destroy']);
$router->add('password/reset/{token:[\da-f]+}', ['controller' => 'Password', 'action' => 'reset']);
$router->add('signup/activate/{token:[\da-f]+}', ['controller' => 'Signup', 'action' => 'activate']);

$router->add('{controller}/{action}');

$router->dispatch($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

[My files/folders structure for site is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqe8r.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You messed up in configuring the server here:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

You actually configured the routes to work in this manner:

```
d-subidha.com/login
```

but due to your server configuration it is not finding any path in your route so it is giving a 404. To solve this change your server rewrite rule.
Your site is working by navigating to url with a "?". eg

```
d-subidha.com?login
```

Working screenshot is attached.
[image]

Comment: Sorry but can you provide me .htaccess rewrite code that will work like d-subidha.com/login.

Comment: @NilmaniGautam Try this: change this line RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L] to RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=/$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: not working, i am putting .htaccess in public folder is that ok ?

Comment: This one is working: RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: I think I have to write it on web.config file. My server is not responding on .htaccess file. How could i convert this .htaccess to web.config file. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Set up the links like this:

`https://d-subidha.com/index.php?login`

It was working for me. 
Or change your RewriteRules.

Comment: thanks but i need to change my .htaccess file and how could i do that